# Unable to reach userName textbox after login failure asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I would like to reach and clear the username textbox (which is in a loginbox) after the user typed his/her username and/or password incorrect. I tried this;

```
((TextBox)loginBox.FindControl("UserName")).Text = "";
```

but I was unable to clear the username textbox or to focus there?

Comment: put more detail in your question at which event you have written the above code etc.

Comment: why not just say `UserName.text = ""`. Not sure what's your question here.

Comment: @Rahul In web forms, you generally have to "find" the control within whatever Naming Container it is in before you can do anything with it.  Since he is using the Login controls, he has to do this.  Silliness, but it is part of the game =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In login tool focus is possible by this code:

```
loginBox.FindControl("UserName").Focus();
```

But as far as I know it is not possible to clean UserName text. iI cannot be cleared like traditional methods. Similarly, most websites keep username but clean password field even user supplied wrong information.

You should change the "UserName" textbox attributes from the code to normal textbox attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems we need to set both the UserName.Text and Login.UserName to an empty string in some event like Login.OnLoginError:

```
<script runat="server">
    void OnLoginError(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)Login1.FindControl("UserName")).Text="";
    Response.Write("Hello!");
    Login1.UserName = "";
}

</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnLoginError="OnLoginError">

        </asp:Login>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" /></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```